# Load high with very little CPU usage?

Tags: cpu-usage, load-average

The load has been sitting at around 6 but there is very little running on the box. Any ideas what's causing this?  It's a large AWS instance.

[image: CPU Load]

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  4      0 4815700 179440 548200    0    0     0     3    2    3  5  1 91  0
 0  4      0 4821256 179444 548192    0    0     0     0  228  373  1  1 48 48
 0  4      0 4821296 179444 548196    0    0     0     0   96  150  0  0 50 50
 0  4      0 4822832 179444 548200    0    0     0     0  158  197  1  1 49 49
 0  4      0 4823452 179444 548200    0    0     0     0   98  149  0  0 50 50
 0  4      0 4823452 179444 548200    0    0     0     0   94  149  0  0 50 50
```

Comment: Please can you post the output of `vmstat 10 6`?

Comment: and check out http://serverfault.com/questions/259613/high-load-average-low-cpu/259626 which this might be similar

Comment: Can you post the regular output from `top` and `iostat`? The most common causes of high loads with low CPU are are high IOWait% and zombie processes.

Comment: Worth noting that there are some reported AWS problems at the moment http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Answer (score 1):

As [noted by James C](https://serverfault.com/questions/262130/load-high-with-very-little-cpu-usage/262135#262135), it looks like you are having trouble with disk IO, not CPU time. If your instance is in the us-east data center [they are having trouble there today](http://status.aws.amazon.com/) and latency to EBS volumes is way up.

Answer (score 0):

The right most column in the vmstat output indicates that there's a lot of i/o wait going on. 50% of CPU time. Could you please post the output of `iostat 10 6` as this should give us a good insight as to which disks are slowing stuff down.

I'm not sure what EBS performance is like but if you're doing a lot of I/O then it might be having problems keeping up.