# High Load Average with modest CPU Utilization and almost no IO

Tags: linux, vmware-esx, high-load

The usual explanation for high load average with little cpu use under linux is too much IO (or more properly [uninterruptable sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_sleep#Uninterruptible_sleep)).

I have a service running on a cluster of 2-core VMs that exhibit modest CPU use (~55-70% idle) but higher than 2 load averages while experiencing near zero IO, modest context switches, and no swapping. Polling with `ps` I never see `D` in the process state column.

The service is ruby 1.9 running under unicorn. It connects to two upstream postgres databases which are delivering very fast avg statement executions (~0.5ms). The service is logging elapsed request durations about twice as high in production as it demonstrated under higher stress load on our performance testing network.  The only monitoring signal which seems out of whack is load average (and of course avg response duration), everything else (cpu, memory, io, network, cswitch, intr) is nominal and matching projections.

System is Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS "Lucid". uname is `Linux dirsvc0 2.6.32-32-server #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 20 22:07:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Hypervisor is VMWare ESX 5.1.

UPDATE: More info as requested by @ewwhite. The storage is a virtual disk device mapping to a an NFS mount on the vm host attached to a NetApp. I'll point out that all indications are that there's no significant disk IO happening.  The service reads and writes to network sockets (~200KB/s) and does ordinary access and error logging (at a rate of about 20KB/s). The vm host has a pair of gigabit ports going to two top of rack switches each of which have bonded four gigabit ports back to a core router, all copper. Each vm host has 24 (4x6) physical cores and 150GB of memory and typically hosts about 30 similarly sized vm guests running a variety of different services. In production these hosts are never over-committed on memory and only modestly over-committed on cpu.

I'd welcome ideas to explain the high load.

Here's some extract sar data from a two hour window midday today:

sar -q # load average

```
              runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15
12:05:01 PM         1       173      1.15      2.41      2.48
12:15:01 PM         0       173      0.96      1.56      1.99
12:25:01 PM         2       173      2.60      2.49      2.21
12:35:01 PM         1       173      1.44      2.10      2.06
12:45:01 PM         0       173      3.66      3.31      2.56
12:55:01 PM         0       173      3.05      2.66      2.43
01:05:01 PM         0       174      1.37      2.35      2.36
01:15:01 PM         0       173      3.06      3.07      2.60
01:25:01 PM         2       173      5.03      6.50      4.50
01:35:01 PM         0       173      4.26      5.61      4.98
01:45:01 PM         8       173      4.61      4.46      4.48
01:55:01 PM         0       173      3.30      3.60      3.92
02:05:01 PM         1       173      2.51      2.62      3.15
```

sar # cpu

```
                CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:05:01 PM     all     31.31      0.60      2.18      0.02      0.00     65.89
12:15:01 PM     all     27.51      0.60      2.07      0.02      0.00     69.79
12:25:01 PM     all     28.09      0.61      1.90      0.03      0.00     69.36
12:35:01 PM     all     32.04      0.67      2.26      0.02      0.00     65.02
12:45:01 PM     all     33.44      0.69      2.61      0.02      0.00     63.24
12:55:01 PM     all     30.62      0.63      2.14      0.02      0.00     66.59
01:05:01 PM     all     29.42      0.61      2.07      0.03      0.00     67.87
01:15:01 PM     all     31.93      0.62      2.39      0.02      0.00     65.05
01:25:01 PM     all     41.60      0.82      3.65      0.03      0.00     53.90
01:35:01 PM     all     43.14      0.88      3.68      0.03      0.00     52.28
01:45:01 PM     all     38.38      0.79      3.43      0.02      0.00     57.39
01:55:01 PM     all     30.65      0.61      2.23      0.03      0.00     66.49
02:05:01 PM     all     29.17      0.58      2.10      0.03      0.00     68.12
```

sar -d # disk

```
                  DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util 
12:05:01 PM    dev8-0      1.37      0.00     35.94     26.14      0.00      3.09      1.98      0.27
12:15:01 PM    dev8-0      1.65      0.00     39.89     24.23      0.00      2.96      1.98      0.33
12:25:01 PM    dev8-0      1.26      0.00     33.39     26.57      0.00      2.89      1.79      0.22
12:35:01 PM    dev8-0      1.33      0.00     35.23     26.52      0.00      3.15      1.82      0.24
12:45:01 PM    dev8-0      1.68      0.00     42.31     25.23      0.00      2.95      1.89      0.32
12:55:01 PM    dev8-0      1.44      0.00     35.76     24.86      0.00      3.20      1.88      0.27
01:05:01 PM    dev8-0      1.43      0.00     35.57     24.93      0.00      2.17      1.46      0.21
01:15:01 PM    dev8-0      1.74      0.00     43.13     24.74      0.01      3.88      2.15      0.37
01:25:01 PM    dev8-0      1.39      0.00     35.36     25.44      0.01      3.65      2.42      0.34
01:35:01 PM    dev8-0      1.32      0.00     33.74     25.65      0.00      3.39      2.09      0.28
01:45:01 PM    dev8-0      1.48      0.00     37.20     25.20      0.01      3.92      2.26      0.33
01:55:01 PM    dev8-0      1.62      0.00     39.36     24.35      0.01      3.27      1.70      0.27
02:05:01 PM    dev8-0      1.42      0.00     34.72     24.51      0.00      3.28      2.13      0.30
```

sar -n # network

```
                IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:05:01 PM      eth0    365.52    359.86    236.91    227.35      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:15:01 PM      eth0    344.55    337.10    221.20    206.47      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:25:01 PM      eth0    357.81    352.76    229.83    216.22      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:35:01 PM      eth0    372.62    366.34    239.95    227.99      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:45:01 PM      eth0    388.65    378.51    252.11    235.81      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:55:01 PM      eth0    364.50    359.19    233.63    222.82      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:05:01 PM      eth0    361.08    353.88    231.75    218.89      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:15:01 PM      eth0    370.41    363.19    240.53    224.16      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:25:01 PM      eth0    357.67    352.20    230.37    213.57      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:35:01 PM      eth0    354.89    348.58    226.29    214.61      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:45:01 PM      eth0    355.49    344.98    228.41    211.27      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:55:01 PM      eth0    335.96    331.13    213.85    204.26      0.00      0.00      0.00
02:05:01 PM      eth0    323.03    314.49    208.12    194.81      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

sar -w # context switches

```
               proc/s   cswch/s
12:05:01 PM      0.97   2382.38
12:15:01 PM      2.58   2415.16
12:25:01 PM      0.84   2406.79
12:35:01 PM      0.84   2371.04
12:45:01 PM      2.70   2414.09
12:55:01 PM      0.84   2385.57
01:05:01 PM      1.20   2419.94
01:15:01 PM      2.57   2387.75
01:25:01 PM      0.85   2164.65
01:35:01 PM      0.84   2156.29
01:45:01 PM      2.53   2251.43
01:55:01 PM      1.01   2331.93
02:05:01 PM      0.96   2323.19
```

sar -B # paging

```
             pgpgin/s pgpgout/s   fault/s  majflt/s  pgfree/s pgscank/s pgscand/s pgsteal/s    %vmeff
12:05:01 PM      0.00     17.97    549.43      0.00    289.21      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:15:01 PM      0.00     19.95   1179.08      0.00    405.61      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:25:01 PM      0.00     16.69    456.71      0.00    217.63      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:35:01 PM      0.00     17.61    480.42      0.00    240.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:45:01 PM      0.00     21.15   1210.09      0.00    424.96      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:55:01 PM      0.00     17.88    489.83      0.00    256.39      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:05:01 PM      0.00     17.79    624.89      0.00    387.26      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:15:01 PM      0.00     21.57   1168.87      0.00    393.34      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:25:01 PM      0.00     17.68    466.03      0.00    235.07      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:35:01 PM      0.00     16.87    435.24      0.00    199.43      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:45:01 PM      0.00     18.60   1125.69      0.00    432.85      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
01:55:01 PM      0.00     19.68    596.62      0.00    272.75      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
02:05:01 PM      0.00     17.36    511.80      0.00    243.83      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

sar -r # memory

```
            kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit
12:05:01 PM   1017364   3041608     74.94    225564   1773324   1194728     16.64
12:15:01 PM   1014992   3043980     74.99    225564   1777268   1193688     16.63
12:25:01 PM   1009504   3049468     75.13    225564   1781360   1194504     16.64
12:35:01 PM    999484   3059488     75.38    225564   1785652   1194520     16.64
12:45:01 PM    994764   3064208     75.49    225564   1790136   1194864     16.65
12:55:01 PM    993772   3065200     75.52    225564   1794288   1194296     16.64
01:05:01 PM    993868   3065104     75.51    225564   1798584   1193428     16.63
01:15:01 PM    985016   3073956     75.73    225564   1802708   1194388     16.64
01:25:01 PM    992316   3066656     75.55    225564   1806804   1192996     16.62
01:35:01 PM    971732   3087240     76.06    225564   1810784   1194272     16.64
01:45:01 PM    968816   3090156     76.13    225564   1815036   1194556     16.64
01:55:01 PM    967968   3091004     76.15    225564   1818716   1194924     16.65
02:05:01 PM    966324   3092648     76.19    225564   1822452   1194516     16.64
```

ps aufx

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:01  \_ [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   1:01  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [watchdog/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:01  \_ [migration/1]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:27  \_ [ksoftirqd/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [watchdog/1]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:37  \_ [events/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:33  \_ [events/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [cpuset]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [khelper]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [async/mgr]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [pm]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:02  \_ [sync_supers]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:04  \_ [bdi-default]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kintegrityd/0]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kintegrityd/1]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:03  \_ [kblockd/0]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:12  \_ [kblockd/1]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kacpid]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kacpi_notify]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kacpi_hotplug]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [ata/0]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [ata/1]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [ata_aux]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [ksuspend_usbd]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [khubd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kseriod]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kmmcd]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [khungtaskd]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kswapd0]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Jan28   0:00  \_ [ksmd]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [aio/0]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [aio/1]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [crypto/0]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [crypto/1]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [pciehpd]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_0]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_1]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kstriped]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kmpathd/0]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kmpathd/1]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kmpath_handlerd]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [ksnapd]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kondemand/0]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kondemand/1]
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kconservative/0]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kconservative/1]
root       213  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:24  \_ [mpt_poll_0]
root       274  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [mpt/0]
root       295  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_2]
root       310  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   1:41  \_ [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       311  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       312  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       342  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:54  \_ [flush-8:0]
root       627  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ [kpsmoused]
root     18160  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb14   0:00  \_ [rpciod/0]
root     18161  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb14   0:00  \_ [rpciod/1]
root     18162  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb14   0:00  \_ [nfsiod]
root         1  0.0  0.0  61824  2872 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:11 /sbin/init
root       372  0.0  0.0  16904   860 ?        S    Jan28   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       375  0.0  0.0  17072  1012 ?        S<s  Jan28   0:00 udevd --daemon
root      1054  0.0  0.0  16860   672 ?        S<   Jan28   0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
root     18163  0.0  0.0  17068   832 ?        S<   Feb14   0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
daemon     654  0.0  0.0   8256   644 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:00 portmap
root       788  0.0  0.0  49260  2592 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      8095  0.0  0.1 100888  4068 ?        Ss   16:03   0:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/0    
root      8157  0.0  0.0  11212  2084 pts/0    Ss   16:03   0:00      \_ -bash
root     15777  0.0  0.0   7172  1084 pts/0    R+   17:28   0:00          \_ ps aufx
statd      808  0.0  0.0  10392   844 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:00 rpc.statd -L
root       829  0.0  0.0    140    32 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:16 runsvdir -P /etc/service log: .....................................................................................................
root       834  0.0  0.0    116    32 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:00  \_ runsv chef-client
root       838  0.0  0.0    136    48 ?        S    Jan28   0:00      \_ svlogd -tt ./main
root     30898  0.2  1.8 192296 75736 ?        S    01:57   2:25      \_ /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/bin/chef-client -i 1800 -s 60 -L /var/log/chef/client.log
root       832  0.0  0.0   6080   656 tty4     Ss+  Jan28   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       841  0.0  0.0   6080   656 tty5     Ss+  Jan28   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       844  0.0  0.0   6080   656 tty2     Ss+  Jan28   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       845  0.0  0.0   6080   660 tty3     Ss+  Jan28   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       847  0.0  0.0   6080   656 tty6     Ss+  Jan28   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root       849  0.0  0.0  21076  1044 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:04 cron
daemon     853  0.0  0.0  18884   468 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:00 atd
root       864  0.0  0.0  11284   640 ?        Ss   Jan28   2:10 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
root       890  0.0  0.0 112412  1908 ?        Ssl  Jan28   5:09 /usr/sbin/automount
root       908  0.0  0.0  28016   976 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data   910  0.0  0.0  64532  3064 ?        S    Jan28   0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
root       922  0.0  0.0 169668  2584 ?        Ssl  Jan28   0:34 /usr/sbin/nscd
mail       943  0.0  0.0  11888   648 ?        S    Jan28   0:00 /usr/sbin/nullmailer-send -d
root       971  0.0  1.1 152036 46264 ?        Sl   Jan28  36:07 splunkd -p 8089 start
root       972  0.0  0.0  49180  3512 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:00  \_ splunkd -p 8089 start
root      1160  0.0  0.0  14888  1276 ?        Ss   Jan28  19:31 /usr/lib/vmware-tools/sbin64/vmware-guestd --background /var/run/vmware-guestd.pid
ntp       1214  0.0  0.0  19700  1268 ?        Ss   Jan28   1:21 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -c /var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp -u 103:107
root      1231  0.0  0.3  21164 12980 ?        SLs  Jan28   0:00 /usr/sbin/memlockd -u memlockd
scs       1270  1.2  2.3 187788 96228 ?        SNl  Jan28 537:27 /usr/bin/ruby /opt/wp/roles/scs/src/dev/scs/bin/server.rb -p 8843
root      1309  0.0  0.0   6080   656 tty1     Ss+  Jan28   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
dirsvc   27448  0.1  1.2 177408 50748 ?        Sl   Feb20   8:57 narwhal master --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.19/confi
dirsvc   13003  2.5  1.2 180012 49128 ?        Sl   16:57   0:47  \_ narwhal worker[1] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   13460  2.5  1.2 180108 49236 ?        Sl   17:05   0:36  \_ narwhal worker[9] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   13637  2.4  1.2 180008 49096 ?        Sl   17:08   0:29  \_ narwhal worker[3] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   13650  2.9  1.2 180172 49420 ?        Sl   17:08   0:35  \_ narwhal worker[11] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.
dirsvc   13701  3.1  1.2 180172 49188 ?        Sl   17:10   0:35  \_ narwhal worker[13] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.
dirsvc   13731  2.7  1.2 181556 50628 ?        Sl   17:10   0:29  \_ narwhal worker[7] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   13770  2.8  1.2 179400 50352 ?        Sl   17:11   0:29  \_ narwhal worker[8] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   13778  3.3  1.2 180104 49172 ?        Sl   17:11   0:34  \_ narwhal worker[5] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   13826  2.6  1.2 181556 50672 ?        Sl   17:12   0:25  \_ narwhal worker[0] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   13939  2.8  1.2 177948 48848 ?        Sl   17:13   0:25  \_ narwhal worker[4] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   13971  3.2  1.4 189052 58292 ?        Sl   17:13   0:28  \_ narwhal worker[12] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.
dirsvc   13982  2.5  1.2 177792 48780 ?        Sl   17:14   0:22  \_ narwhal worker[6] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   15316  3.0  1.2 180072 49128 ?        Sl   17:20   0:15  \_ narwhal worker[2] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.1
dirsvc   15381  2.0  1.2 179944 48928 ?        Sl   17:21   0:08  \_ narwhal worker[14] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.
dirsvc   15743  3.5  1.1 177624 48596 ?        Sl   17:28   0:00  \_ narwhal worker[10] --port 8862 -c /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.
dirsvc   27461  0.1  1.3 235884 54744 ?        Sl   Feb20   9:20 /opt/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby /opt/wp/roles/directory/src/dev/directory/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wp-directory-svc-2.1.19/gem-bin/wo
root     11068  0.0  0.0 130480  1720 ?        Sl   04:20   0:00 rsyslogd -c4
zabbix   18062  0.0  0.0   9908   728 ?        SN   11:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd
zabbix   18063  0.0  0.0   9908   756 ?        SN   11:41   0:12  \_ /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd
zabbix   18064  0.0  0.0   9980  1044 ?        SN   11:41   0:03  \_ /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd
zabbix   18065  0.0  0.0   9980  1044 ?        SN   11:41   0:03  \_ /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd
zabbix   18066  0.0  0.0   9980  1044 ?        SN   11:41   0:03  \_ /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd
zabbix   18067  0.0  0.0   9908   660 ?        SN   11:41   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd
```

EDIT: More info by request:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep vmware
vmware-open-vm-tools-common         install
vmware-open-vm-tools-kmod-2.6.32-32-server  install

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 44
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5660  @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 2
cpu MHz     : 2800.099
cache size  : 12288 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat
bogomips    : 5600.19
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 44
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5660  @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 2
cpu MHz     : 2800.099
cache size  : 12288 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat
bogomips    : 5600.19
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: You neglected to mention anything about the underlying storage, connection medium, hardware, version of VMware, whether VMware Tools are installed, etc.

Comment: @ewwhite added requested info. (Except I can't answer "etc." because the world is too big to fully describe. :)

Comment: Three years later, this service and its hosting architecture is long gone, but the puzzling question remains.  I recently read this paper on Linux scheduler bugs and wonder if interplay of these bugs with the vm execution might have been the culprit. http://www.ece.ubc.ca/~sasha/papers/eurosys16-final29.pdf

Comment: Since this Q comes up when Googling, I'd like to leave a link to [the excellent article on Linux "load averages" by Brendan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html), which has the most comprehensive description of load averages (and what metrics to look at instead).

Answer (score 13):

Load average is based on the processes waiting in the run queue.  That means if you have processes that use fractional time slices often you can see a high load average without a high CPU utilization.

The best example of this is mail.  The amount of CPU time require to send a message is very limited, but when thousands of pieces of mail are moving around the system (especially if the mail daemon forks processes to handle each one) the run queue gets very long.  It is common to see well functioning, responsive mail servers with load averages of 25, 50 to over 100.

For a web server I would use page response time as the primary metric, do not worry about load average.  Under modern schedulers load average less than twice the number of cores will usually have no negative effects.  You may want to experiment with number of cores per VM versus total number of VMs.  Some applications will benefit from many cores on a few machines, others are better at a small number of cores and many instances.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What constitutes a "fractional time slice"? As I understand the scheduler, a process gets assigned to a cpu and runs on that cpu until the next scheduling interval or until it makes a blocking system call which causes it to yield. It my cpu is idle 70% of time but my run queue lengths average over 2, that puzzles me, why aren't these ready-to-run processes just getting scheduled to the mostly idle cpus?

Comment: I would add that this is a web service, though not a web server. It does have an execution profile akin to a bunch of other similar services we run: receive and deserialize a request, perform some dispatching to upstream services/databases, compute a result based on the answers from the upstreams, serialize a response, scribble a log msg. Median request duration ~60ms, 90% 200ms, 99% 500ms+. We have a bunch of other services with similar profiles running on comparable vm containers that do not exhibit this disconnect between Load and CPU%.

Comment: Linux is only going as far as scheduling to a virtual cpu though, which ESX then schedules via it's own algorithms to a real cpu. How similar are the comparable vm's? Very similar CPU for different load? Same memory usage?

Comment: @mindthemonkey There's at least a couple dozen different services in the VMs. Some have substantially different profiles, but the majority look pretty similar to this service. 4GB mem, 2 virt cpus, modest IO (mostly network and basic logging), run 30-60% cpu utlization through the daily curve. IO and/or memory intensive nodes (DBs, SOLR) get dedicated hosts.  Most of these other service vm's show the expected correlation between cpu% and load (at least as long as they stay healthily away from 100%).

Comment: @mindthemonkey while the guest scheduler is only controlling the virt cpu and ESX is scheduling in the larger context, I don't see how this substantially effects the cpu% and load accounting.  Both are based on samples taken at some frequency and to the extent the guest is pre-empted by the hypervisor scheduling, that will effect both the slices where real work gets done and slices where the guest takes its samples.

Comment: Sorry, was heading down the path of what would be stolen cycles.. which you have 0 of =)

Comment: Actually, scratch that. It appears that kernel doesn't enumerate the stolen value so you will need to check for the "READY" counters in ESX for your vmm. Are these VM's ready values higher than others? Do they have any entitlements, shares, limits set lower in ESX?

Comment: @Matt I'm currently dealing with this same issue in a very similar environment. Nearly identical symptoms to dbenhur. I followed your advice to check for "READY" counters (stolen cycles). Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be the culprit. Our high-load VM only has 1-3 cycles stolen per second, which is the same as our healthy VMs.

Answer (score 1):

If we use following shell commands to monitor the real load average, we might have different views on this phenomenon.
procs_running could be much higher than we expected.

```
while true; do cat /proc/loadavg ; cat /proc/stat| grep procs; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with a scenario very similar to yours. In my case, the load average dropped after changing the IO scheduler of the problematic VM's block device to the NOOP scheduler. This scheduler is just a FIFO queue, which works well when the hypervisor will apply its own IO scheduling algorithms anyway. No need to reorder twice.

With that said, I'm still dealing with sluggish keyboard events on the problematic VM, so I think I've only removed the high load average without resolving the actual problem. I'll definitely update this answer if I find the root cause.

List available schedulers (and [scheduler] in use):

```
cat /sys/block/sdX/queue/scheduler
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]
```

Change it with:

```
echo noop > /sys/block/sdX/queue/scheduler
```

To make it persistent, you need to add `elevator=noop` to your VM's kernel boot parameters.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a performance problem in a VM first you need to approach the problem from both supervisor side and from VM. Another thing to keep in mind is that timekeeping in a VM is not precise. This also means that stats measured in a VM might not be correct.

What are the CPU and I/O stats for this VM? Pay attention to CPU ready counter - it should be under 5%. Which version of ESX are you running on? What is your hardware architecture in test and prod?

On VM you can profile everything from application to kernel with [perf](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) and visualize the output with [flamegraphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to address a five year ago problem -- the systems and software in the question belong to a company I no longer work at and the VM stack and the service in question are no longer in operation there anyway. :)  There's a bunch of CPU and IO info already posted in the original question. Brendan's public work and exposition on perf and flamegraphs postdate this question by more than a year.

Comment: No problem. Maybe it will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a particularly high load average. If you want to track it down, `iotop` is probably the best tool for the job.

Comment: `iotop` is boring, everything says approximately 0.

Comment: Any load avg above cpu count means I have more processes waiting to run than cpus to run them. I see many intervals above 2.0 and several la-5s over 4 and up to 6.5.  This means I often have processes that are stalling for cpu behind other processes and implies unwanted latency for lack of cpu capacity.  I normally expect load average and cpu% to correlate until the system starts approaching 100% cpu saturation; after that load average is the better signal because it indicates how over-committed the system is, not just that it's 100% busy.

Answer (score -2):

The load average is the number of runnable processes waiting for the CPU. A process that is waiting for I/O doesn't count at all. The "usual explanation" is just dead wrong.

Comment: Linux includes processes in uninterpretable sleep in its load calculation. Such processes show with State 'D' in the usual process inspection tools. This state is usually used by device drivers waiting for disk or network IO. That "usual explanation" is true for Linux, but not most other unixes.

Comment: s/uninterpretable/uninterruptible/

Comment: A comment earlier referenced some performance work from Brendan Gregg which reminded me that he also recently did some lovely archeology on how [Uninterruptible Sleep wound up in Linux's Load Average](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html)