# High load average but low CPU usage and disk I/O

Tags: linux, load-average

I’m encountering a strange issue on one of my servers. This is on a KVM VPS which has one dedicated CPU core.

Sometimes the load spikes to around 2.0:
[image: Load graph]

However, CPU usage doesn’t actually increase during that period, which also rules out iowait being the cause:
[image: CPU usage graph]

It seems periodic when it happens (eg. in this graph it happened roughly every 20-25 minutes). I suspected a cronjob, but I don’t have any cronjobs that run every 20 mins. I have also tried disabling my cronjobs and the load spike still occurs.

I managed to actually see this happening while SSH’d into the server… It had a load of 1.88, but the CPU was 94% idle and there was 0% iowait (which is what I expected the cause might have been)

[image: <code>top</code> output]
[image: <code>htop</code> output]

There does not appear to be a lot of disk I/O when this happens.

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: @anx This is at a VPS provider, so unfortunately I can't really snapshot the KVM guest. I only have access to the guest, not the host. Also, I don't have /proc/pressure on my system. Does that need a kernel patch? I'm on Linux kernel 4.19.0

Comment: 3) https://serverfault.com/questions/482832/high-load-average-with-modest-cpu-utilization-and-almost-no-io?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I worked this out... It turns out it was caused by the software I was using to monitor the server (Netdata).

Linux updates the load average every 5 seconds. In fact, it actually updates every 5 seconds plus one "tick"

[sched/loadavg.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/include/linux/sched/loadavg.h#L20):

```
#define LOAD_FREQ   (5*HZ+1) /* 5 sec intervals */
```

[sched/loadavg.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/345671ea0f9258f410eb057b9ced9cefbbe5dc78/kernel/sched/loadavg.c#L12-L26)

```
 * The global load average is an exponentially decaying average of nr_running +
 * nr_uninterruptible.
 *
 * Once every LOAD_FREQ:
 *
 *   nr_active = 0;
 *   for_each_possible_cpu(cpu)
 *  nr_active += cpu_of(cpu)->nr_running + cpu_of(cpu)->nr_uninterruptible;
 *
 *   avenrun[n] = avenrun[0] * exp_n + nr_active * (1 - exp_n)
```

`HZ` is the kernel timer frequency, which is defined when compiling the kernel. On my system, it's `250`:

```
% grep "CONFIG_HZ=" /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_HZ=250
```

This means that every 5.004 seconds (5 + 1/250), Linux calculates the load average. It checks how many processes are actively running plus how many processes are in uninterruptable wait (eg. waiting for disk IO) states, and uses that to compute the load average, smoothing it exponentially over time.

Say you have a process that starts a bunch of subprocesses every second. For example, Netdata collecting data from some apps. Normally, the process will be very fast and won't overlap with the load average check, so everything is fine. However, every 1251 seconds (5.004 * 250), the load average update interval will be an exact multiple of one second (that is, 1251 is the least common multiple of 5.004 and 1). 1251 seconds is 20.85 minutes, which is exactly the interval I was seeing the load average increase. My educated guess here is that every 20.85 minutes, Linux is checking the load average at the exact time that several processes are being started and are in the queue to run.

I confirmed this by disabling netdata and manually watching the load average:

```
while true; do uptime; sleep 5; done
```

After 1.5 hours, I did not see **any** similar spikes. The spikes **only** occur when Netdata is running.

So... in the end... The app that I was using for monitoring the load was the one responsible for causing it. Ironic. He could save others from death, but not himself.

It turns out other people have hit similar issues in the past, albeit with different intervals. The following posts were extremely helpful:

- [Investigation of regular high load on unused machines every 7 hours](https://blog.avast.com/investigation-of-regular-high-load-on-unused-machines-every-7-hours)
- [Understanding why the Linux loadavg rises every 7 hours](https://mackerel.io/blog/entry/tech/high-loadavg-every-7-hours)
- [Telegraf - high load average every 1h 45m](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/3465)
- [Linux commit that changed load average calculation to be every 5 seconds + 1 tick, instead of exactly every 5 seconds](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/0c2043abefacac97b6d01129c1123a466c95b7c1)

Reported it to the Netdata devs here: https://github.com/netdata/netdata/issues/5234. In the end, I'm not sure if I'd call this a bug, but perhaps netdata could implement some jitter so that it doesn't perform checks every one second exactly.